# Nodejs return HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I am fairly new to node and javascript and I am having trouble storing the information from an HTTP request into an object which I can use outside of the request.

I am looping through another object to get the path for the HTTP request and trying to store the response in another object which can be used outside of the loop.

```js
function apiRequest(){

    var options = {        
        hostname: 'us-central1-dpduk-s-test-d1.cloudfunctions.net',
        path: '',
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            Authorization: ' Bearer A416EB2A-5B7F-4A85-9E32-75CDB8F4F0F6'            
       }
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){

        options['path'] = '/parcels/' + jsonObj[i].parcel_number;    

        var res = http.request(options, function(res) {

            var respones = '';       

            res.on('data', function(data){
               respones += data;
            })

            res.on('end', function(){
               var routesETA = JSON.parse(respones);

            });
        })
        res.end();    
    } 
}
```

I just keep running into routesETA not defined.

Comment: For anyone wonder how i got around this, I added a count variable to record how many times I did a http request and used that to access my object to insert the results of the request.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're declaring the variable routesETA inside of a callback, if you want to use it outside the for loop you should declare it along with the options:

```
var options = {        
    hostname: 'us-central1-dpduk-s-test-d1.cloudfunctions.net',
    path: '',
    method: 'GET',
    headers:{
        Authorization: ' Bearer A416EB2A-5B7F-4A85-9E32-75CDB8F4F0F6'            
   }
}, routesETA;
```